# How do I roll back a kernel upgrade?

Tags: kernel

I am using the Occidentalis distro and stupidly ran apt-get upgrade without thinking about the repercussions.  After a reboot I now am on a stock kernel, which means I lost kernel support for OneWire, which was my reason for using Occidentalis.

Is there any way for me to undo what I did, short of reimaging the SD card?

Comment: Does your kernel still exist? It should be in `/boot/` and the headers in `/usr/src/`. Show us the output of `ls` in those two directories?

Comment: Check out [this](http://superuser.com/q/38717/199877) question.

Comment: Try out Jiving's suggestion by running `ls /boot/ && ls /usr/src/` and posting the results. That will give us a better chance of giving you an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could mount the SD Image under Linux using `sudo mount -o loop occidentalis.img /mnt/sd` (the directory /mnt/sd must exist.) Then cd to /mnt/sd/boot/ and do `sudo cp kernel.img /boot/kernel.img`

Reboot and 1-wire support will be enabled.

**This may not be necessary however.**
Newer versions of Raspbian (which you now have as you updated the system) there is a kernel module called w1-gpio. Put this in your /etc/modules. You will also want to add w1-therm if you use a 1 wire temperature sensor such as a DS18x20.